# Infimum of $(\frac{1}{n}+\cos(\pi n))$ Question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, supremum-and-infimum

I have to prove the following:

> $\inf\left(\frac{1}{n}+cos(\pi n)|n\in \Bbb N\right)=-1$

I thought that if I prove that $\inf(A+B)=\inf(A)+\inf(B)$ I can solve the question, since $\inf\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$ and $\inf(\pi n)=-1$, so the sum is $-1$.

Can I use this approach solving the question?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: In general inf(A+B) $\geq$ inf A + inf B.  Not necessarily equal.

Comment: remember that $\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n$. Then you can directly calculate your result by inspection.

Comment: Try to picture two continuous functions being added together to create a third, i.e. $f_{1}(x) + f_{2}(x) = g(x)$. Now suppose that $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ have infimums at different points. Does $\inf{g} = \inf{f_{1}} + \inf{f_{2}}$? Although it may work for your question, in general it is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix $n$ odd, then you have the subsequence $-1 + \frac 1n$ and clearly 
$\inf \left(-1 + \frac 1n\right) = -1 + \inf \left(\frac 1n\right)$.

If you fix $n$ even, then the subsequence is $1 + \frac 1n$ which is always bigger than the other one so we don't really care about it.

Comment: I just can split it to subsequences and see who's infimum is smaller? that's it? Thank you.

Comment: @Alan Yes you can :-) of course make sure you're not "forgetting" any number when you do so, otherwise it won't work. But in this case yeah :)